# Windows 10 update - can't change keyboard language

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, keyboard, language

After updating of `Windows 10 Pro` to new version `1903` (around 20ths January 2020) changing of keyboard language does not work. I have 2 different languages on the system.

Comment: is this about mantaining an IT system in business environment? Otherwise, the question would better fit SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

Solved for me after deleting of duplicated English keyboard for my second language.

1. Go to `Parameters - Time and Language - Language`
2. Click on your language (not English) at the buttom of the page, `Parameters`.
3. Click on English keyboard at the buttom of the page of your language and `Delete` that keyboard.

---

If this did not help, see also [Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/i-cant-change-keyboard-language-by-win-space/21d87f1e-d745-41e2-b5b7-6394da70b842)